# how to insert one table record value to other table using oracle form as a mediator

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

i have two tables :

**`table1( columns as id, name, mail, address)`** and **`table2(eid, name, mail and salary)`**

i have created data block for each table (name datablock1 and datablock2).
Table2 is a new table and the form have some fields like name, mail, address which gets data from table1.

Now when i save the form with some values in fields the similar **`data(name, addresss)`** from table should be inserted to **table1**.

i'm using below code but it is not saving data to **`table1`** ;

1. is there any other way to insert data to **`table1`** ?
2. please elaborate how to go further ?

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1
    (ID,
     name,
     mail,
    address)
  VALUES
    ( SEQ.NEXTVAL,
     :datablock2.name,
     :datablock2.mail,
     'sometxt');
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

During the creation of a **`Database Block`** through use of the **`Data Block Wizard`**, it would ask you to provide a table name(namely **`table1`** in this case), and its columns.

After creation, you'll see

- *`Database Data Block`* under *`Database`* node of the *property palette* set to **`Yes`**
- *`Query Data Source Type`* to **`Table`**
- *`Query Data Source Name`* to **`table1`**

And just click on the *diskette icon* after entering some data to the fields of the *`table1`* block provided that the *`Menu Module`* under *`Functional`* node of the of the *property palette* of the form is set to *`DEFAULT&SMARTBAR`*

Otherwise, you just can add a *button* to a canvas with only having the code

```
COMMIT;
```

in order to save the entered data to the table by clicking on it.